# Blank space occupied when ads are not showing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using admob_flutter plugin to display ads in my app. Everything is working fine but when ads are not ready to display or someone is offline then I am getting blank space on the place of ads Banner. like image below
[image]

I tried boolean method too but I can'nt figure out the problems.

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _storyListByCategory.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index % 7 == 0 && index != 0)
              return Column(
                children: [
                  AdmobBanner(
                    adUnitId: AdManager.bannerAdUnitId,
                    adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
                  ),
                  StoryByCategory(
                    this._storyListByCategory[index],
                  ),
                ],
              );
              else return StoryByCategory(
                this._storyListByCategory[index],
              );
            },
        ),
```

Please suggest me how can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool _adShown=true;
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _storyListByCategory.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index % 7 == 0 && index != 0)
          return Column(
            children: [
              _adShown?AdmobBanner(
                  adUnitId: AdManager.bannerAdUnitId,
                  adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
                  listener: (AdmobAdEvent event,m){
                    if (event == AdmobAdEvent.loaded) {
                      setState(() {
                        _adShown=true;
                      });
                    } else if (event == AdmobAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
                      setState(() {
                        _adShown = false;
                      });
                    }
                  }
              ):Container(),
              StoryByCategory(
                this._storyListByCategory[index],
              ),
            ],
          );
        else return StoryByCategory(
          this._storyListByCategory[index],
        );
      },
    ),
```

You shall use listener in admob to check whether ad has loaded or not.

Answer (score 1):

import 'dart:io';

before your return Widget

```
  bool isonline = false;
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    isonline = true
  }
```

then in your list :

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _storyListByCategory.length + isonline ? 1:0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index % 7 == 0 && index != 0)
              return Column(
                children: [
                  isonline ? AdmobBanner(
                    adUnitId: AdManager.bannerAdUnitId,
                    adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
                  ), : 
                  AdsMakemeliveWidget() ,
                  StoryByCategory(
                    this._storyListByCategory[index],
                  ),
                ],
              );
              else return StoryByCategory(
                this._storyListByCategory[index],
              );
            },
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In that type of cases you can always use ternary operator.
here is simple example :-

- create a function which check internet connectivity continuously then call this function before building widget tree..
- then use  SizeBox.shrink() to shrink.

*description :-

- checkNet():for checking internet connection.
- _wiget():Simple widget
- set ? _wiget() : SizedBox.shrink(), _wiget() : ternary operation
- set :bool variable
- the most import thing is to call checkNet() Continuously so for that call checkNet() every time before building widget.*

  ```
   class EnrollCourse extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _EnrollCourseState createState() => _EnrollCourseState();
  }

  class _EnrollCourseState extends State<EnrollCourse> {
  bool set;
  @override
  void initState() {
   // TODO: implement initState
   super.initState();
   checkNet();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   checkNet();
   return Scaffold(
     body: Center(
       child: new Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: [_wiget(), set ? _wiget() : SizedBox.shrink(), _wiget()],
       ),
     ),
   );
  }

  void checkNet() async {
   try {
     final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
     if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
       setState(() {
         print("yes internet");
         set = true;
       });
     }
   } on SocketException catch (_) {
     setState(() {
       print("No internet");
       set = false;
     });
   }
  }

  Widget _wiget() {
   return Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: new Container(
       color: Colors.red,
       height: 200,
       width: 200,
       child: new Text("child 1"),
     ),
    );
  }
  }
  ```